The partition function is given by taking the trace of a density matrix. How do I convert this sum to an integral with correct factors?
I am learning Quantum Statistical Mechanics from Kardar's Book on Statistical Physics of Particles, in that he does the following for the partition function of a 3D gas:
$Z_1 = tr(\rho) = \sum_k exp\left(-\cfrac{\beta \hbar^2 k^2}{2m}\right) = V \int \cfrac{d^3 \vec{k}}{(2\pi)^3}\; exp\left(-\cfrac{\beta \hbar^2 k^2}{2m}\right)$
Where $k_x, k_y, k_z$ can take the values $\frac{2\pi}{l} * (n_x, n_y, n_z)$, and $n_x, n_y, n_z \in \mathbb{Z}$.
The part I have a problem with is the factor of $\frac{V}{(2\pi)^3}$ in the third equality. I think the general problem I have with this is how take a trace of an infinite dimensional matrix. This seems pretty simple but I understand this explains the arbitrary planck's constant we add in the classical partition function.
So if someone can explain how to get that factor, or in general how to convert this type of a sum to an integral, I would really appreciate it.

I'l do one dimension. Going to three is straightforward.
Suppose F(k) is smooth  function of $k$, then, when $L$ is large, $F(2\pi n/L))$ is a slowly varying function of $n$.  Then, as  $n= kL/2\pi$,  we can use the Riemann definition of the integral as the limit of a discrete sum to write
$$
\sum_n F(2\pi n/L ) \approx \int dn F(2\pi n/L)=L \int \frac{dk}{2\pi}F(k),
$$
where $n$ in the integral is now a continous variable.The approximation become exact when $L$ is large.
The Planck constant is not arbitrary: Energy $=p^2/2m$ where   $p =mv=  \hbar k$ is Planck's formula.

Oh I see... If I understand you correctly, the Reimann sum you have performed is with respect to $\Delta n = 1$. Another way to right your expression would be:
$\frac{1}{\Delta n} \sum_n F(k) \Delta n$?
If i were to expand it directly in terms of k, it would be:
$\frac{1}{\Delta k} \sum_n F(k) \Delta k$
Where $\Delta k$ is $\frac{2\pi}{L}$?

Exactly! Actually I like your rewrite using  $\Delta k= 2\pi \Delta n/L$

Thanks for the clarification and help!
